# Can I use wildcard to wildcard mappings in a DNS CNAME record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have multiple https services running on different subdomains of *.domainA.com, but they are all configured with a wildcard certificate for *.domainB.com.

I believe the record below would allow me to access the services, but is it in fact a valid DNS record?

`*.domainB.com    CNAME     *.domainA.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an A record for *.domainA.com in domainA.com's DNS zone, your dns record would work. You won't achieve to have sub1.domainB.com pointed to sub1.domainA.com, as each subdomain on domainB.com will point to *.domainA.com.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping dns would employ wildcard search/replace when translating, but wildcards are only used to find a record.  Thank you for clearing that up!